# Redirect http://www.domain.com to https://www.domain.com using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect my domain from http to https:

```
http://www.domain.com --> https://www.domain.com
```

Is it possible? I've been searching around the internet but I only found:

```
http://domain.com --> https://www.domain.com
```

The question is, how about peoples arriving directly on http://www.domain.com? Aren't they be served with non-https url? Same as the vice versa. I just want a simple redirection from the HTTP to HTTPS. Is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work for ALL versions of php and will force SSL and www to all naked domains and links:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

- We DO need the NE
- www. is optional in 4th line
- "off" is required to be.

Answer (score 2):

`I just want a simple redirection from the HTTP to HTTPS`

Try this simple rule **as first rule on your .htaccess**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: combining yours with Merianos Nikos's = Magic. I want from non-www redirected to www. and then, from www they'll redirect to https. it's perfect. thank you both! ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code for force www and SSL usage:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off

# Now, rewrite any request to the wrong domain to use www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^tatwerat\.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}

</IfModule>
```