# .htaccess redirect from www.domain.com to https://domain.com

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have struggling and searching with no luck.

What I want is to redirect from `www.domain.com` to `https://domain.com`.

I have successfully solved for `domain.com` to `https://domain.com` by setting the following .htaccess as folows:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22282815/1883256) and the `www.domain.com` does not redirect to `https://domain.com`, it only stays `www.domain.com` and it doesn't display anything.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this single rule to do both `http -> https` and `www` removal:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing.